# hide button after its been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The issue I am having is that I want the submit button hidden after
I have chosen a date from a calendar. and submitted it.
The html/script I am using is
...

```
<input type="button" value="Try it" id="Submit1"  onclick= "myFunction();this.form.submit();">

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Submit1");
  x.hidden= true;
}
</script>
...
```

When you have clicked the button it hides the button for a second but then appears again.
I guess this when the page is reloaded.
Anybody have a solution for this.

Its being written in Classic asp VB

Comment: Either don't reload the page by using AJAX to submit the form instead, or store the visible state of the button somewhere (cookie, localStorage, session) and then show/hide it on the next reload based on that state

Comment: So what exactly do you want to fix? Form submission typically navigates to a new page instead of displaying the form again, so what is your form's `action`?

Comment: The form reloads itself, after the date has been added it brings back data relating to that date. to stop the user clicking the date submit button.

Comment: Ok, but if it's supposed to be possible to use the form again, does it make sense to hide the button? And if the user *isn't* supposed to use the form a 2nd time, why show the form to them at all?
I'm trying to grasp the user experience here, because it seems to be very weird.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  var x = document.getElementById("Submit1");
  x.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

But this code should be executed after reloading the page, which means that the body of the new page just needs to have code

```
<script>
    window.myFunction();
</script>
```

The backend side (php, ruby, node ...) can take care of this.

You can call the code from the browser console (F12, then CTRL + `). This will give you a feel for what code you need to run and when.